# How can I detect and handle my app when the device is connected as Mass Storage?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sd-card, usb-mass-storage

I developing a game with SD resources. When I connect the device as MASS STORAGE the device crash. It's because when I plug my device in the PC as Mass Storage the device doesn't have access to the SD card. So I tried different ways to solved.

Currently I'm implementing a BroadcastReceiver and I'm handling the actions ACTION_MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL (if the SD card is removed manually) and ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED (it supposed to handle the action if the device is connected as Mass Storage, but it doesn't).

When both of these actions is detected I send an error message and I finish the app.

When I remove the SD card manually it works, but not as mass storage.

Also on every frame I check if the SD card is on the device on every frame with this method.

```
 public int hasSDCard()
 {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state))
                return 1;
    return 0;
 }
```

When is 0 it doesn't have SD card and that where I also send the error message and finish the app.

But stills doesn't work on USB Mass Storage mode.

My question are: **How can I detect when the device is connected as USB Mass Storage** ?

**What classes should I use?**

**Which listeners I can implement to call my error message activity and finish my app?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BroadcastReceiver` class. At the begining register a BroadcastReceiver for `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` or `ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED` intent. Create a class that will override `onReceive()` method, which is the method where you handle the mounting/unmounting.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED

As an extra info read the deprecation of `ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_UMS_CONNECTED

Comment: I didn't work. I'm blame the onResume method on the main activity. It try to access something on the SD card before onReceive.

Comment: Cant you do that in onReceive()? If you cant, then instantiate the receiver in your activity as class variable instead class that `extends`BR

Comment: OnReceive only works if I remove the SD Card manually. It's the same thing if I extend it or if  declare it as a variable. I'll try something else thanks.

Comment: Did you remove the code that has to be working when onReceive method is called? I mean the one in onResume() you've mentioned.

Comment: Well, I assume (from what you said) that the code that has to access something on SD is in onResume(), now I'm telling you to try removing (or move it) to onReceive() method and in that method try to access the SDcard. Makes sense?